# Community user rejects edit made to questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, community-user, rejected-edits

I have edited many questions on Stack Overflow but I came across one issue that [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) rejected edits I made to question and same edit suggested by other user was approved. So after rejection I edited same post and was approved by Stack Overflow user. This is really irritating when you put efforts to edit post and same gets rejected by Community user.

Few rejected edits by Community user:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2177250
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2177543
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2177078
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2162831

Comment: I assume you meant to say "Community User" instead of "Community wiki", is that correct?

Comment: No, it's community wiki only

Comment: Now it is changed to community..here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Comment: @R.S - Can you show some examples of rejected edits?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits

Comment: Also see feature request: [Add a reject reason when the Community user rejects an edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/add-a-reject-reason-when-the-community-user-rejects-an-edit)

Comment: @hims056,I have  [M](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2086702)  [A](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1931666)  [N](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1931442)  [Y](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1931478), this communaughty rejected my edits which were approved by edit reviewers

Comment: @Azik - See the answer on [a duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127378/187824). Also you can support [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153403/187824)

Comment: @hims056, I have upvoted [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/add-a-reject-reason-when-the-community-user-rejects-an-edit) post two months ago

Comment: This is almost the same as [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181453/monitoring-of-rejected-edits-and-rejecting-editors)', 5 minutes ago. All the edits listed are minor changes, if you do a good edit it will get accepted.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - Not the same. Even it is not related. That question is about rejected edit by *community*. While this question is about rejected good edit by *community user*

Comment: @JeremyThompson ...Read my question carefully ..Here i am talking about Community User and not about Stackoverflow user

Comment: Why downvote? Can you please explain?

Comment: @JeremyThompson - Also if you think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2177250) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2177543) are minor edits then what is *non-minor* and accepted edits?

Comment: @JeremyThompson..If you think those were minor edits then why those edits got approved by other users?

Comment: @R.S **minor edit** is a subjective concept. Each Stack Overflow user has its own interpretation of what is considered as minor. So some users approve and others may reject the same edit.

Comment: @AzizShaikh...You are right,I accept what you say..But if you look at my some edits ,you would find that those were really acceptable.

Comment: @hims056 both of those edits have issues though. The first leaves the code block split in half, the second leaves a lot of unfixed issues and abuses bold text, doesn't fix the caps and leaves the redundant "thanks"

Comment: @Flexo and what about last two suggestions ?